# How do android:shrinkColumns and android:stretchColumns work?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, stretch, shrink

I can set `android:shrinkColumns` and `android:stretchColumns` at  `TableLayout`.

For example:

```
<TableLayout
    android:shrinkColumns="2,3"
    android:stretchColumns="1,3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

So how do this properties affects columns?

Comment: May I suggest reading the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) - The docs for TableLayout clearly explain what these do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TableLayout can specify certain columns as **shrinkable or stretchable by calling `setColumnShrinkable()(xml:android:shrinkColumns) or setColumnStretchable()(xml:android:stretchColumns)`**.

If marked as ***shrinkable***, the column width can be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space.

The total width of the table is defined by its parent container. It is important to remember that a column can be both **shrinkable and stretchable** .

For details information you may visit

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 15):

- android:stretchColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to stretch. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored. You can stretch all columns by using the value "*" instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable at the same time.
- android:shrinkColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to shrink. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored. You can shrink all columns by using the value "*" instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable at the same time.
- android:collapseColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to collapse. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored.

  ```
  <TableLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:background="@color/grey">

  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:background="@color/red"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/green"
          android:text="2" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          android:text="3" />
  </TableRow>


  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:background="@color/red"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/green"
          android:text="2" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          android:text="3" />
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  ```

Explanations:

> android:stretchColumns="*"

[image]

Means it stretch all columns equally according to table layout width

> android:shrinkColumns="*"

[image]

Means it shrink  all columns

> android:shrinkColumns="0,2"
>
> android:stretchColumns="1"

[image]

Means column 0 and 2 are wraps contain and column 1 stretch into the available width

> android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
>
> android:shrinkColumns="1"

[image]

Means if column already stretch then shrink not apply

> android:shrinkColumns="*"
>
> android:collapseColumns="1"

[image]

android:collapseColumns means it hides given column

> android:stretchColumns="*"
>
> TextView :- android:layout_column="2"

[image]

Meaning if table row first column layout parameter does not start with 0 then empty view added into the row

> android:stretchColumns="*"
>
> android:collapseColumns="1"
>
> TextView :- android:layout_column="2"

[image]

Means if  table-row first column layout parameter does not start with 0 then empty view added into row  but if you collapse column then added empty view not hide of that column index only hide added view by explicit view

I hope this will help.

Comment: stretchColumns and shrinkColumns are 0 based column. That means the first column is 0 not 1.

Comment: Thank you sir, very nice explanation

Comment: Why do you need android:layout_column="0", etc. as it is auto assigned

Comment: @PayelSenapati good question..i write every child with its position because while reading or coding its easy to understnd which coloumn i am working on…what have to do when i have more then 15-20 or 50 coloumn how to know while scrolling up/down in xml which coloumn i am currenty focusing ? its easy to describe every coloumn with its position so don’t have to confuse or count every coloumn while scrolling or doing some operation …i just read the coloumn index from child view its easy for me